# Understanding 'implements' and 'with' in Dart

Tags: oop, interface, dart, polymorphism, mixins

I am just reading Dart language specification and exploring a new interesting language. [As Dart language specification says](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#classes): Dart has `implicit interfaces`. Which means every `class` is an `interface` too. So, If I want to implement some behavior of another class, `implements` clause is the only I need.

Also, Dart supports `mixins`. So that we can take implementation of methods from another class using `with` keyword.

So, given that if an abstract class A defines method a() like :

```
abstract class A {
  void a();
}
```

and another two concrete class B defines method a() but does not implements class A like:

```
class B {
  void a() {
    print("I am class B");
  }
}
```

and class C implements class A with Mixin B like :

```
class C extends Object with B implements A {
   ...
}
```

Here, I have few questions about it. If a class implements the interface and also use mixin that has method implementation with same method name; doesn't it would make `cycling inheritance` possible?
What will be the behaviour of `class C`? Does it need to implement `a()` or it will be implicitly implemented by `mixin B`?

I am just learning Dart and concepts like mixins are very unfamiliar to me. Can anyone help me understanding by answering my questions?

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but fixed your samples to be correct Dart

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus So,if I use mixin using with clause is that class restricted to extend Object? I read it somewhere but didn't understand it. Can you please elaborate something about your edit?

Comment: You wrote `class C implements A with B { ...}` The correct syntax is `class Classname extends Baseclass with Mixinclass implements Interface{...}`. *Any* class may be extended. There are restrictions on classes that can be used as mixins though. I suggest reading the Language Tour section on classes for better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixins are a kind of limited multiple inheritance. With `C with B`, `C` inherits an implementation of `void a()`. Adding `implements A` doesn't need anything more to be done, because `C` already fulfills the contract it claims to fulfill by `implements A`, because of `B`.

Answer (score 2):

Your link is to the *Language Tour*, not the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf), but the tour is definitely what you should be reading to start with.

Your example is just fine. `class C extends Object with B { ... }` basically adds the members of B to Object to create C. If C then satisfies the interface A it can declare support for that interface ( `implements A` ).